# How to have an async class updates itself inside of another class

Tags: python, class, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

Let's imagine we have a parent class and a child class. The parent class is responsible for analyzing specific data inside the child class, and the child class is responsible for keeping that data updated based on a WebSocket connection. I wonder if I can initialize the child class in the parent class and then have it get updated async?

This is how it might look:

```
class Analyze:

   def __init__(self):

    self.data_service = Child()

   def analyze_data(self):
    While True:
       # Do some analysis on self.data_service.data


class DataService:

   def __init__(self):
    self.data = pd.Dataframe()
    self.update()


   async def update(self):
    # update self.data based on a WebSocket service async

anlz = Analyze()
anlz.analyze_data()
```

Note: I would rather not integrate these two classes since each has many features.

Comment: Let's not imagine anything, let's discuss this with a code outline (even if it won't work) in your post instead =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for the comment. I updated the question and added a sample code to illustrate what was in my mind.